# How to make content of a (cck) field visible when pressing a button?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am working on a Drupal 7 website and I would like to create a node where a specific (cck) text field is only shown to the users after they press a button.

The effect I would like to achieve is exactly the same you can find in the Careers 2.0 website where, at the end of each job post, there is a button titled "Find out how to apply". When you click on this button the "how to apply instructions are shown". To see how it works you can check http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/10860/foursquare-software-engineer-scala-lift-foursquare?campaign=Featured.

Can somebody please help?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript you would need is

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.togglebutton').length) {
      //hide box if there is a button to toggle it on
      $('.cckfield').toggle();
    }
    $('.togglebutton').click(function() {
      $('.cckfield').toggle();
    });
    $('.togglebutton').css('cursor', 'pointer' );
  });
})(jQuery);
```

there is many places where you can add this script.  The first one that comes to my mind is `MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)` in MYTHEME/template.php file

```
MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&variables) {
  if ($node->type == 'jobposting') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', MYTHEME') . '/name-of-js-file.js')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is in the theme. Simply add the CSS and JS needed for this effect. Should be pretty simple as all fields has unique ids.